# How to dynamically create wrapper classes for 3rd party library classes?

Tags: c#, oop

I am writing a library that depends on another library and utilizes some of it's design.

There are about 10 or so container classes that just hold data. I need an exact wrapper for these 10 classes so the client code of my library does not have to declare the 3rd party library as a dependency in their project.

I'm curious if there is a way to easily create wrappers for these classes without manually creating a file and definition of the classes / fields.

My initial solution was to just extend from the 3rd party library class like this.

```
using LibFooOne = SomeLibrary.SomeNamespace.FooOne;
using LibFooTwo = SomeLibrary.SomeNamespace.FooTwo;
// ...

public class FooOne : LibFooOne { }
public class FooTwo : LibFooTwo { }
// ... And so on for the 10+ other classes
```

But once I tested my library in a example project, there was a compile error complaining that the 3rd party was not referenced in the project assembly.

So far the only working solution I have figured out was to manually create an exact copy of the 3rd party library classes, and write type cast methods for each of them.

Any possible way I can dynamically create these copies so does not force the client code to install the 3rd party library? Is there a library to handle this type of task?

**Edit: My question wasn't asking if I could some how make my initial solution work. I was simply using it as an example for my end goal. I'm asking if there are libraries or way in c# to wrap classes. I can create a class with the same fields, and create a casting method. This works and solves my issues. However it's a lot of manual work.**

Comment: You can use [`DynamicProxy`](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/) from the [Castle Project](http://www.castleproject.org/) to create run-time proxies from objects.  This won't remove the requirement for a reference to the original objects though.

Comment: Could you use Nuget packages to solve the issue. Or can you not deploy the 3rd party dlls

Answer (score 0):

No: You are subclassing classes stored in third-party assemblies. You will need those assemblies on the target machine when your program runs.

If you have the source code to the third-party assemblies in question and you have the licensing rights, you could subclass and compile your own version of the third-party assembly. But it doesn't sound like you have the source code to those third-party assemblies.

Comment: My question wasn't asking if I could some how make my initial solution work. I was simply using it as an example for my end goal. I'm asking if there are libraries or way in c# to wrap classes. I do have the source code, but I don't need it. I can create a class with the same fields, and create a casting method. This works and solves my issues. However it's a lot of manual work.